# C# - How to do a volume slider

Tags: c#, xna

I am making a game using the XNA 4.0 Framework. I have been attempting to make a volume but I was not able to figure it out. The main problem is how to determine the length of the slider to properly represent the volume(0.0f - 1.0f). I mainly just need advice on how to clean it up.
Here my code for the current slider that I have:

```
private void VolSlider(int moveSpeed)
    {
        if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.PageUp) && prevKb.IsKeyDown(Keys.PageUp))
        {
            buttonSliderRec.X += moveSpeed;
            MediaPlayer.Volume = Math.Min(1.0f, MediaPlayer.Volume + 0.001f);
        }
        if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.PageDown) && prevKb.IsKeyDown(Keys.PageDown))
        {
            buttonSliderRec.X -= moveSpeed;
            MediaPlayer.Volume = Math.Min(1.0f, MediaPlayer.Volume - 0.001f);
        }

        //Resets the volume to default
        if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && mouse.X >= 494 && mouse.X <= 720 &&
            mouse.Y >= 163 && mouse.Y <= 230)
        {
            MediaPlayer.Volume = 0.5f;
            YouLoseInst.Volume = 0.5f;
            YouWinInst.Volume = 0.5f;
            onClickInst.Volume = 0.5f;
        }
    }
```

I call this subprogram in Update inside a switch statement. I was just wondering how to properly make the slider represent the Volume function and advice on how to fix up my code shown up above.

Comment: Why not use two sprites, one a line, another the slider-bar. Then you can get input on the user dragging it, and change it's position based on key-press volume changes?

Comment: @Monacraft can you explain that last bit more please. I didn't quite understand what you mean

Comment: check me answer for my elaboration

Comment: @Monacraft thanks a lot man. That helped me understand it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer elaborating on how to make a slider using sprites.

For this you would require two sprites:

1. A line/bar representing the limits of the volume
2. A small button that is drawn on the line representing current volume

#### Update Logic

Have it so that if:

**a.** The user hits the keyboard buttons the increase/lower volume, you appropriately change it.

**b.** If the user clicks on the *line* sprite, it set's the volume based on where on the sprite they clicked on (get mouse.X and subtract the **far left x-val** of the volume bar, then divide by total length of vol bar for a percentage)

(Note, you would not need to worry about them clicking and dragging the button sprite, since they would indirectly click on the volume bar so it would just use that code)

#### Draw Logic

Draw the button sprite completely relative to the line sprite, so that they are scaled equally.

1. The y-value is always the center of the line sprite
2. The x-value is **the far let x-val** of the line sprite + the current volume (As a percentage) * the width of the line-sprite.

Notice you require the far left x-val of the line sprite for both getting and setting the volume. This way, the volume of the game could be controlled via key-presses, dragging the bar *and* clicking anywhere on the bar. It also means that the position of the bar is always the actual volume, allowing people to check if it is in fact working.

I haven't provided any code examples for this but would be more than happy to (you'd have to give me a bit of time to write it up)

Comment: if i read that correctly in the update method i would use this MediaPlayer.Volume = ((mouse.X - volSliderRec.X) / volSliderRec.Width)